# Как можно сделать файлы недоступными для отображения галерее?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Допустим я использую память телефона как хранилище картинок, но не хочу, чтобы галереи их показывали. Что делать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В папке с картинками создайте файл с названием

```
.nomedia
```

И сканирование медиафайлов в этой папке производиться не будет.

Comment: Так вот что это) Спасибо) Видел их но не понимал зачем !